# db2: Alter Table fails when a related view exists

Tags: db2, alter-table

Error running the line:

```
alter table m_produc ALTER COLUMN DES_PROD SET DATA TYPE CHARACTER(80);
```

*SQL0727N  An error occurred during implicit system action type
"3"*

My guess is the existence of related views in preventing the modification...

Its similar to this

[Quickly dropping and re-creating multiple indexes, views, statistics when altering a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18281686/quickly-dropping-and-re-creating-multiple-indexes-views-statistics-when-alteri)

Only difference: it's MSSQL

It's there any way to deactivate that implicit behavior, run the line and activate it again, maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [DB2 Information Center](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql00727n.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F2-6-27-1-122&lang=en) has some steps that you can take to solve your problem (it also lists what the "action types" mean... in your case `3` means "implicit revalidation of an object"):

> ***User response***
>
> Check the message associated with the `SQLCODE` of the SQL statement
>   that failed. Follow the action suggested by that message.
>
> For an invalid package, the `REBIND` command can be used to recreate the
>   error or to explicitly validate the package once the cause of the
>   error has been resolved.
>
> For a failure that occurred while a database object was being
>   revalidated:
>
> Determine the name of the database object that could not be revalidated by locating the revalidation failure message in the
>   administration notification log.
>
> To avoid this error in the future, you can do one of the following:
>
> - If the database object that is causing this error is no longer needed, drop the database object.
> - If the statement or command that caused this database object to be revalidated can be changed, change the statement or command so that the next time that statement is executed or that command is run the database object will not be revalidated.
>
> Revalidate the database object now by doing one of the following:
>
> - Execute an SQL statement that directly references the database object.
> - Call the ADMIN_REVALIDATE_DB_OBJECTS procedure for the database object.
>
> Federated system users: If the statement that failed was dynamically
>   prepared in a pass-through session, open another pass-through session,
>   write and prepare the statement again, and execute it while the
>   session is still open.

Comment: `db2diag.log` will likely show the exact object that fails revalidation.